# symbolic summation involving kronecker delta

Tags: symbolic, summation

I have to perform symbolically summations of this kind

$\sum_{ijkl} V_{ijkl} c_i c_j c_k \delta_{l,m}$

where $V_{ijkl}$ are quantities which depend on 4 indices and $\delta_{l,m}$ is the kronecker delta.
Is it possible in mathematica to perform the summation in order to obtain the symbolical result

$\sum_{ijk} V_{ijkm} c_i c_j c_k$?

I just tried with

```
Sum[V[ijkl] d, i,j,k,l]
```

where d contains terms of the kind $c_i c_j c_k \delta_{l,m}$.

Comment: How did you go from the top symbolic expression to the bottom one? What are the limits of summation? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Don't use `D` as your own symbol name; that's a *Mathematica* built-in for the derivative function. In general, never use uppercase for user-defined symbols, as they could conflict with *Mathematica* built-ins.

Comment: If you want to work extensively with index notation you might want to consider external packages like Ricci: http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Ricci/

Answer (score 4):

In the documentation of `KroneckerDelta` says:

> Use in sums to pick out elements:

```
Sum[KroneckerDelta[a, 3] f[a], {a, Infinity}]
(*f[3]*)
```

Just do the sum in `l` with `{l,Infinity}`

```
Assuming[m > 1 && 
  m \[Element] Integers, Sum[
   KroneckerDelta[l, m] f[m], {l, Infinity}]]
(* f[m] *)
```

`f` is your other sums.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with `Sum[V[i j k l] d, i,j,k,l]`. In mathematica `xy` is not the same thing as `x y`. Mathematica interprets `xy` as a variable but it interprets `x y` as `x * y`, so if you wanted to to `V[i*j*k*l]` try that. Sorry if this wasn't much help.